# Choose the right type for method GetById

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, asp.net-web-api

I designed my repository class and I need some advice from you. Now I have a method `GetByID` that returns a generic type:

```
 public T GetById(object id)
 {
    return this.Entities.Find(id);
 }
```

I'm going to use `OData` to filter data, and for that (when I'm using `$expand` for single row) I need to do something like this:

```
SingleResult.Create(repository.GetByID(id));
```

But of course I received an error because `SingleResult` needs a type `IQueryable<T>`.

So, I decided to change my `GetByID` to:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetById(object id)
{
    return this.Entities.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == (int)id);
}
```

Could you please tell me if is it the right way? What type should be returned from `GetByID`?

I prefer to use `T GetById` because it is more correct in my opinion, but I don't know.

Comment: `GetById` returns one result or the default value for `T`. Why then I you trying to pass this to `SingleResult.Create`? Why create a `SIngleResult<T>` when you already have `T`?

Comment: Yes, but without `SingleResult` my OData like `http://localhost:3761/api/Street/1?$expand=StreetType` not work

Comment: Ah, I missed the bit about OData. Your question effectively highlights the problem with that standard. Returning `IQueryable<T>` feels wrong and that's for very good reasons: a queryable abstraction is a leaky one. You may like to read https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/is-using-odataiqueryable-in-your-web-api-an-inherently-bad-thing/ and http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/ before committing yourself too much to this solution.

Comment: There are some issues with this code. Doesn't FirstOrDefault only return a single object not a collection? Also, what type is Entities? DbSet? What's the point of calling a DbSet method in a generic repository? Doesn't that couple it to the entity type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you're only going to make the minimal required change

Accommodate the IQueryable requirement in the layer where it is needed, not in your repository layer. That will probably be some object that takes in an entity, wraps it in an `IEnumerable`, and calls `AsQueryable()` on it. (Disclaimer: This may or may not work. I haven't tested it.) If you were to do otherwise and change your repo signature to use `IQueryable`, that would be coupling the repository layer to downstream requirements, which you are correct in wanting to avoid.

### A side pet peeve

Please avoid using `object` in signatures if you're going to use generics in the same class and you don't have a reason to box (I believe DbSet has to use reflection to find the key so it has a boxing requirement, but your code does not require boxing). Use strong typing all the way until you absolutely must cast to object. You'll thank me later.  And make the parameter names expressive:

```
public TEntity GetById<TKey>(TKey id)
{
    return this.Entities.Find((object)id);
}
```

### Digging deeper

It seems a bit wonky and counterintuitive to have to pass an `IQueryable` to `SingleResult`. But come! Join me on a journey in pursuit of greater understanding of this "`IQueryable`".

An `IQueryable` is a bit more than just a collection. It functions as a sort of gateway to the data you're after, letting you query that data without having to use its unique language (SQL, or OData queries, what have you). This is accomplished through an associated query provider, which translates the lambda expressions you provide it to the language of your data store.

More importantly, that query provider decides how to compose and manage queries, and that includes utilizing deferred evaluation. The fact that you can pass it a query from your EF context is its way of telling you "I got this bro. This IQueryable has all I need to pull the data from here when I need it." It will then pull the data it needs for the OData query it's building on demand.

If you instead return it an entity, you have eagerly loaded that entity from the DB yourself, when you may not have needed to. Or at the very least, before you needed to.

### A Catch-22

Using the generic repository here directly pits the benefits of IQueryable (deferred evaluation, the need for less "intermediary" code) against the reusability of a library that abstracts data access away from queries (is this even being reused?). In order for these two to coexist, some compromises are going to have to be made, compromises that may result in an extremely mediocre "solution."

### A simpler appeal

If you look at the way the OData provider functionality is designed, it's evident that it's meant to directly consume EF context queries *including in your web app layer*. If the DbContext was meant to be shut away inside a library, they would have designed things a lot differently.

### To sum up

I would recommend reconsidering the purpose of your generic repository, why you need it, and what it's buying you.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm not sold on the concept that it's meant to be used directly in the WebApp layer. A useful abstraction on top of it, in between, can be... useful.

Comment: @RubberDuck tautologies aside, it depends on what utility the abstraction is providing. The improved mockability of `DbSet` and `DbContext` in tandem with an injected factory to create the context is sufficient to completely decouple from the database and test your code in isolation. In my opinion that's good enough for a large majority of enterprise code. Beyond that is the world of DDD and abstracting *everything* behind a layer, which is a completely different beast.

Comment: @RubberDuck Plus, check out the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)...static context instantiated with the controller, disposed when the controller's disposed. All that's needed to make it testable is to inject a context factory.

Comment: It's not about testability, it's about useful abstractions. Real world databases often aren't well structured. Adding a layer of misdirection allows us to compensate for it and further decouple from the persistence layer.

Comment: @RubberDuck what decoupling does a generic repository provide that DbSet doesn't? Especially considering that a generic repository does nothing to change the structure/representation of the db types at all (something that can be handled elegantly with `EntityTypeConfiguration` anyway)

Comment: I wasn't talking about OP's code. I was talking about your assertion that EF is designed to be used directly in the application layer. We agree that the generic repository idea is most often misguided.

Comment: @RubberDuck Right on. Let me be clear: The EF DbContext should be sufficient for all scenarios in which you do not need a domain model. If you don't have a domain, but you're building walls around EF, it's probably going to become a big ouchie.